# BigQuery subquery return numbers based on all outer columns

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery, correlated-subquery

Consider the below query:

```
#standardSQL
WITH table AS (
  SELECT
  *
  FROM
  `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*`
  WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20180118'
  )
SELECT
date,
device.deviceCategory,
CASE WHEN totals.newVisits IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END newUser,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT returningUser) FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN totals.newVisits IS NULL THEN fullVisitorId END returningUser FROM table)) returningUser
FROM
table
```

This returns the below:

[image]

As you can see, `returningUser` is a sub-query which isn't correlated to the outer query columns.

Question is, how do you go about getting the `returningUser` numbers based on the outer query columns? Ideally, I wouldn't want to join on outer query columns, as the requirement is returningUser number against all of these columns.

I want to be able to update this query to add more outer query columns as well as more sub-queries where their numbers are based on all outer query columns.

**UPDATE**

The data-set is from Google Analytics. The fields are default fields, example data-set available at https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416091

Example query that returns expected results - however, this is not as clean and flexible as the above method which I'm trying to get working:

```
#standardSQL
WITH table AS (
  SELECT
  *
  FROM
  `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*`
  WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20180118'
  )
SELECT
date,
deviceCategory,
COUNT(DISTINCT returningUser) returningUser
  FROM (
  SELECT
    date,
    device.deviceCategory,
    CASE WHEN totals.newVisits IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END newUser,
    CASE WHEN totals.newVisits IS NULL THEN fullVisitorId END returningUser
    FROM
    table)
GROUP BY
date,
deviceCategory
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've added the example query that returns desired results - thanks for your help so far

Answer (score 2):

I can't make sense of what you really want the query to do.  My best guess is:

```
SELECT date, deviceCategory, COUNT(newVisits),
       COUNT(DISTINCT COALESCE(s.newVisits, s.fullVisitorId))
FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*` s
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20180118'
GROUP BY date, deviceCategory
ORDER BY date, deviceCategory;
```